# Is there a better way to merge rows and delete duplicates in a pandas dataframe, possibly using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that contains some data as shown below.

| Sample | Protein Name | Peptide | Calc. Mass | Score sample_1 | Score sample_2 | Score sample_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample_1 | Name_1 | KIITHPNFNGNTLDNDIMLIKL | 2283.1802 | 128.3 |  |  |
| sample_2 | Name_1 | KIITHPNFNGNTLDNDIMLIKL | 2283.1802 |  | 202.5 |  |
| sample_1 | Name_2 | KVQQYRV | 693.3678 | 52.2 |  |  |
| sample_1 | Name_3 | RLCSGNPDSVETLEQPAVPILSALPKQ | 2635.3647 | 305.2 |  |  |
| sample_2 | Name_3 | RLCSGNPDSVETLEQPAVPILSALPKQ | 2635.3647 |  | 450.6 |  |
| sample_N | Name_3 | RLCSGNPDSVETLEQPAVPILSALPKQ | 2635.3647 |  |  | 362.7 |

I want to copy sample scores of matching peptides into one row and remove the duplicates. I wrote this set of loops and it works but I'm wondering if there's a better way. One caveat is that the number of samples run will be different on each day so I need to be able to adapt to different numbers of columns.

```
def finalize(final_df):
    for item in list_pep:
        Row = (final_df.index[final_df["Peptide"] == str(item)].tolist())
        for i in Row:
            try:
                if final_df.iloc[i+1, 2] == final_df.iloc[i, 2]:
                    for item in sam_col:
                        value = final_df.at[i, item]
                        isNaN = np.isnan(value)
                        if isNaN == True:
                            pass
                        else:
                            final_df.at[i+1, item] = final_df.at[i, item]
                else:
                    pass
            except IndexError:
                pass
    final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates("Peptide", keep='last')
    return final_df
```

Here is my desired output based on the above table. I didn't include the part to delete the sample column.

| Protein Name | Peptide | Calc. Mass | Score sample_1 | Score sample_2 | Score sample_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | KIITHPNFNGNTLDNDIMLIKL | 2283.1802 | 128.3 | 202.5 |  |
| Name_2 | KVQQYRV | 693.3678 | 52.2 |  |  |
| Name_3 | RLCSGNPDSVETLEQPAVPILSALPKQ | 2635.3647 | 305.2 | 450.6 | 362.7 |

Comment: `drop_duplicates` might work for you.

Comment: @Sid I do use drop duplicates to remove them, but I need to put all of the scores into a single row so I don't lose them. Does drop_duplicates have a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a complicated custom function, simply use:

```
final_df = df.groupby(['Protein Name'], as_index=False).agg('first')
```

output:

```
  Protein Name    Sample                      Peptide  Calc. Mass Score sample_1 Score sample_2  Score sample_n
0       Name_1  sample_1       KIITHPNFNGNTLDNDIMLIKL   2283.1802          128.3          202.5             NaN
1       Name_2  sample_1                      KVQQYRV    693.3678           52.2            NaN             NaN
2       Name_3  sample_1  RLCSGNPDSVETLEQPAVPILSALPKQ   2635.3647          305.2          450.6           362.7
```